# Why is SSIS Conditional Split including unwanted data regardless of condition?

Tags: ssis

I have the following condition set in `SSIS Conditional Split` to send all invalid address to the Output Name `InvalidOutput`.

However, I keep getting some addresses with `Null` `Address1 column`. I am not sure why.

```
ISNULL(LEN(TRIM(Address1)) > 5) || 
ISNULL(LEN(TRIM(ZipCode)) == 5) || 
ISNULL(LEN(TRIM(City)) >= 5) || 
ISNULL(LEN(TRIM(Province)))
```

Comment: Also see http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/808c06da-a570-424e-872c-378d78769e6f/why-is-ssis-conditional-split-including-unwanted-data-regardless-of-condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Jayvee said, you have to treat your conditions separatly (Separate between the ISNULL fonction and other controls) your condition will become like this :

```
ISNULL(LEN(TRIM(Address1)) > 5) || 
ISNULL(LEN(TRIM(ZipCode)) == 5) || 
ISNULL(LEN(TRIM(City)) >= 5) || 
ISNULL(LEN(TRIM(Province)))
```

Become :

```
(ISNULL(Address1) || LEN(TRIM(Address1)) <= 5) || 
(ISNULL(ZipCode) || LEN(TRIM(ZipCode)) != 5) || 
(ISNULL(City) || LEN(TRIM(City)) < 5) || 
(ISNULL(Province) || LEN(TRIM(Province)) = 0 )
```

Comment: So I have to evaluate for null in front of everything? Make sense now.

Answer (score 2):

if your address1 is null then ISNULL(LEN(TRIM(Address1)) will be True but then True > 5 won't be True.
You need to treat the nulls separatel; e.g.

```
ISNULL(Address1) || LEN(TRIM(Address1)) > 5
```

Comment: Is there a way to check for empty string?

Comment: Address1=="" or len(address1)==0

Comment: Yeah, I tried that before and I get the error: `Conditional Split Requires Boolean`.